# How to verify if rect is inside cv::Mat in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there anything like `cv::Mat::contains(cv::Rect)` in Opencv?

**Background:**
After detecting objects as contours and trying to access ROIs by using cv::boundingRect my application crashed. OK, that's because the bounding rects of the object close to image border may be not entirely within the image.

Now I skip the objects not entirely in image by this check:

```
if(
  cellRect.x>0 && 
  cellRect.y>0 && 
  cellRect.x + cellRect.width < m.cols && 
  cellRect.x + cellRect.width < m.rows) ...
```

where *cellRect* is the bounding rect of the object and *m* is the image.
I hope there is a dedicated opencv function for this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simple way is to use the **AND** (i.e. **`&`**) operator.

Assume you want to check if `cv::Rect rect` is inside `cv::Mat mat`:

```
bool is_inside = (rect & cv::Rect(0, 0, mat.cols, mat.rows)) == rect;
```

Comment: Probably not the fast solution, but interesting one. `(rect & rect_mat)` would create a new Mat object and == would compare all cells. This will be for sure slower, than getting and compating 4 numbers x,y,w,h.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Not a new `Mat`, a new `Rect` actually, which is basicly just 4 numbers `(x, y, width, height)`. So it should be relatively fast. :P

Comment: OK, got it! Now it looks elegant indeed!

Comment: The parentheses around operator `&` is important. I got a nonsense error without that.

Answer (score 5):

You can create rect "representing"(x,y = 0, width and height equal to image width and height) your image and check whether it contains bounding rects of your contours. To achieve that you need to use rect intersection - in OpenCV it's very simple, just use `rect1 & rect2`. Hope that code makes it clear:

```
cv::Rect imgRect = cv::Rect(cv::Point(0,0), img.size());
cv::Rect objectBoundingRect = ....;
cv::Rect rectsIntersecion = imgRect & objectBoundingRect;
if (rectsIntersecion.area() == 0)
  //object is completely outside image
else if (rectsIntersecion.area() == objectBoundingRect.area()) 
  //whole object is inside image
else 
  //((double)rectsIntersecion.area())/((double)objectBoundingRect.area()) * 100.0 % of object is inside image
```

Comment: Interesting! I'd never intuitively grasp, that & means intersection in OpenCV. Good to know! So it looks like there is no built-in function like Rect::contains(Rect)? Why? it seems to me that this is a very common and useful function.

Comment: I think that there is no such function, because one rect can contains other rect in 100%, not at all(0%) or in any part between 0-100%. If you want to check whether rect1 contains rect2 completely just use this code `bool contains = (rect1 & rect2).area() == rect2.area()`. Note that this code will return true if rect2.area() will be 0 (so width or height will be equal to 0), if you don' want this, use this code: `bool contains =  rect2.area() && (rect1 & rect2).area() == rect2.area()`. Hope it's what you need :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a method to judge whether a rectangle contains an other rectangle.
you can get the size info from `cv::Mat first`, and then use method below:

```
public bool rectContainsRect(Rectangle containerRect, Rectangle subRect)
{
    if( containerRect.Contains(new Point(subRect.Left, subRect.Top)) 
        && containerRect.Contains(new Point(subRect.Right, subRect.Top))
        && containerRect.Contains(new Point(subRect.Left, subRect.Bottom))
        && containerRect.Contains(new Point(subRect.Right, subRect.Bottom)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: are you kidding ?